# How to Prevent Updates over Broadband?

Tags: windows-7, updates, mobile-broadband

My broadband connection is metered with steep price jumps at set levels of bandwidth consumption. The WiFi internet connections I use however are unlimited. Therefore, I would really not want any application to update when I am on the broadband connection.

Windows update behave relatively well in that regard since I let the notification but set to download and update on demand. For other applications like Java, Avira, Acrobat, etc, they seem to simply update at any time. I would rather have these only update on WiFi or check and ask before downloading.

How can I enforce this on Windows 7?

Comment: You can do this in the individual programs or with the updater program. Or you can install a firewall that blocks requests..

Comment: If you detail how, you've answered my question. In the obvious places, no such settings were found yet. I'd rather not disable updates completely but right now it's costing me too much.